# Is it possible to have a hidden input in a form that uses GET?

Tags: html, forms, input, hidden

Is it possible to do this?

```
<form action="/process_form" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="some_value" value="top_secret" />'
```

Comment: What makes you think this _isn't_ possible?

Comment: How hidden do you need it do be? The HTML you posted is in regular use since the mid-nineties.

Comment: Hidden inputs are simply not rendered on the page by the browser. Otherwise they are they same as input in a text field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it's possible, but the value will be visible in the URL you request when the form is submitted.  I hope your value isn't actually top secret.  Actually, the value is visible to the client in any case, so it had better not be secret.